# Creating a Fall-Through Route Rule after the Default Rule

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, routeconfig

How can I create a fall-through (fallback) route for products after the default route that maps to a product controller?

Instead of example.com/product/laptop I want example.com/laptop

/product is an application that does all sorts of work. However, the product name is dynamic and new ones are added all the time.

If a route exists, then it should use the default:

> example.com/about/
>
> example.com/about/shipping

Otherwise, it is a product, and should fall through to the last route rule:

> example.com/{dynamic product name fallback}
>
> example.com/laptop
>
> example.com/mouse
>
> example.com/iphone

I have tried the fallback all, but it never gets to the Product controller, and it does not pass the product name which I need.

```
 url: "{*.}"
```

**RouteConfig:**

```
      routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "About", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Fall Through to Product",
            url: "{productname}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index" }
        );
```

**Controller**

```
 public class ProductController : Controller
 {
    public ActionResult Index(string productname)
    {
        return View();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really. The default route is the default route because it catches just about everything. However, what you can do is handle the 404 by first trying to find a matching product.

In your Web.config, add the following:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto">
  <remove statusCode="404" />
  <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error/notfound" />
</httpErrors>
```

Then create `ErrorController`:

```
public ActionResult NotFound()
{
    // Get the requested URI
    var uri = new Uri(Regex.Replace(Request.Url.OriginalString, @"^(.*?);(.*)", "$2"));

    // You slug will be the `AbsolutePath`
    var slug = uri.AbsolutePath.Trim('/');

    // Attempt to find product
    var product = db.Products.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Slug == slug);

    // If no product, return 404 error page
    if (product == null)
    {
        return View("~/Views/404.cshtml");
    }

    // Otherwise, return product view
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    return View("~/Views/Product/Product.cshtml", product);
}
```

Comment: Instead of removing the status code in the web.config, can I set it in the controller? So, the product would be Response.StatusCode =200 and the normal 404 would be Response.StatusCode = 404. It seems like the product pages would return 404 otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that's actually very important. Sorry that I neglected that. Answer has been updated. You still need to remove it in the Web.config, though. That's for a separate purpose.

Comment: No, you need the Web.config stuff exactly as I posted it. The `<remove>` gets rid of any default handlers  for that status code, while the `<error>` instructs how to handle the error, i.e. rewrite it to `/error/notfound`, so it's handled by your controller.

Comment: I just realized the confusion my previous comment created. When I said "remove it in the Web.config", I was referring to the handler. In other words you *need* to *keep* the `<remove statusCode="404" />`. I wasn't telling you to actually remove that line from the Web.config.

Comment: Come again? `Request.Url.OriginalString` will contain the the *error* URL with actual requested URL tacked on to the end separated by a semi-colon. That's why I did a `Regex.Replace` in my code above. Sounds like you neglected to add that. Also, remember that you're tying into the 404 handler here. Which means *all* 404s will hit this action. Whether that be just a generic route that didn't match or for a missing static resource like an image.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. I'm going to delete and clean up my extended comments.